# Output of List of game board states shows all states to be identical

Tags: java

I am in process of building the game of Tic Tac Toe. I have 3 classes in the logic.

- **Board**:  Defines all the board related functions.
- **Game** : It is the main class that will make use of all the different classes.

I have attached a code snippet of the program.

1. **getAllStates**:This function should return all the available states/nodes that can be explored.
2. If I pass an object of class board and the player as evident from the function call in Main(Game) Class `ar = getAllStates(b,2);`
3. This means if I pass a Board instance like

   000 
   000
   000

This should return an ArrayList with all possible states like:

```
200
000
000
```

and

```
020
000
000
```

and

```
002
000
000
```

and so on upto

```
000
000
002
```

However, when ! execute the code and check the values stored in the ArrayList, I get an ArrayList of 9 objects each with configuration:

```
000
000
000
```

The Code

```
    public class Game2 {            

        static int player1 = 1;
        static int player2 = 2;

        public static void main(String[] args) {            

            //playGame();
            ArrayList<Board> ar ;               
            Board b = new Board();
            Computer comp = new Computer();             
            ar = getAllStates(b,2);                     
            //System.out.println(comp.getConfigScore(b));               
        }     

        public static ArrayList<Board> getAllStates(Board b, int player)
        {               
            ArrayList<Board> arr = new ArrayList<Board>();
            for(int i = 0;i <3; i ++)
            {
                for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    if(!b.isPosOccupied(i, j))
                    {        
                        int previousState = b.getVal(i, j);
                        b.setVal(i, j, player); 
                        b.display();                    
                        arr.add(b);
                        b.setVal(i, j, previousState);
                    }                       
                }                   
            }

            System.out.println(arr.size());
            return arr;             
        }           
    }

The Board Class is :

public class Board {        
    // Defines Board Configuration
    static int[][] data = new int[3][3];        
    public Board()
    {           
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++ )
        {
            for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++ )
            {
                data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Displays Current State of the board    
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Board");            
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j< data.length;j++)
            {
                    System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }       

    // Gets the Value on a specific board configuration
    public int getVal(int i, int j)
    {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    //Sets the value to a particular board location
    public void setVal(int i, int j,int val)
    {
        data[i][j] = val;

    }       

    public boolean isBoardFull()
    {
        for(int i=0;i< data.length ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j< data.length ;j++)
            {
                if(data[i][j] == 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isVictoriousConfig(int player)
    {           
        //Noting down victory rules
        //Horizontal Victory
        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [0][1]) && (data[0][1] == data [0][2]) && (data[0][2] == player)))
            return true;            

        if   ((data[1][0] != 0) && ((data[1][0] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [1][2]) && (data[1][2] == player)))
            return true;            

        if   ((data[2][0] != 0) && ((data[2][0] == data [2][1]) && (data[2][1] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;            

        //Vertical Victory          
        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [1][0]) && (data[1][0] == data [2][0]) && (data[2][0] == player)))
            return true;        

        if   ((data[0][1] != 0) && ((data[0][1] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][1]) && (data[2][1] == player)))
            return true;            

        if   ((data[0][2] != 0) && ((data[0][2] == data [1][2]) && (data[1][2] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;

        //Diagonal Victory          
        if   ( (data[0][0] != 0) && ((data[0][0] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][2]) && (data[2][2] == player)))
            return true;            

        if   ( (data[0][2] != 0) && ((data[0][2] == data [1][1]) && (data[1][1] == data [2][0]) && (data[2][0] == player)))
            return true;

        //If none of the victory rules are met. No one has won just yet ;)          
        return false;           
    }

    public boolean isPosOccupied(int i, int j)
    {
        if(data[i][j] != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;           
    }       
}
```

Since I am updating the board configuration in the getAllStates() function to give all the possible configuration of board, I don't understand why does the ArrayList() show such a result.

I feel either I am overwriting this array list somewhere or I am not updating the array list at all with the expected board configurations. I would really appreciate any thoughts here.Kind of badly stuck. Thanks in advance.

Added Edit: Alright, so if I change my setter to give back a different object of b, it should work. Then is this modification right?

```
public Board setVal(int i, int j,int val)
    {
        Board newboard = new Board();
        data[i][j] = val;
        newboard.data = data;
        return newboard;

    }
```

After this, I would add do something like this in the **getAllStates()** funtion

```
Board newboard = b.setVal(i, j, player);                    
arr.add(newboard);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to clone the board in order to change it again and again while storing previous states. Otherwise you're changing the same object. You end up with a list referencing the same object.

You can verify like this:

```
ar = getAllStates(b,2);
ar.get(0) == ar.get(1); // returns true
```

I would override the `Board.clone()` method and use it like this:

```
arr.add(b.clone()); // replaced arr.add(b);
```

Another option is to make `Board` objects [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). This can be done by always creating another object once mutated (usually in setters). So `Board.setVal(...)` would return a **new** board object with the new set value:

```
public Board setVal(...) {
    // ...
    // TODO: create a clone of the board named newBoard
    // ...
    return newBoard;
}
```

Once you've changed the interface you can do this:

```
// keeps old object that may still be referenced from changing
b = b.setVal(i, j, player);
```

*Note*: To make an object conceptually immutable it may be needed to make it's internal objects immutable as well. If you're representing a `Board` using an internal array, you will need to make it immutable by never changing it as well.

This can be done upon construction by passing the array and copying it immediately discarding the reference to the external array:

```
public Board(int[][] data) {
    this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length); // copy array
    // do not reference 'data'. Do not expose 'this.data'.
}
```

Comment: Is this the correct way of modifying the setter function? public Board setVal(int i, int j,int val)
 {
  Board newboard = new Board();
  data[i][j] = val;
  newboard.data = data;
  return newboard;
  
 }

Comment: You'll have to clone the array as well for the exact same reasons. Take a look at `Arrays.copyOf(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the `ArrayList` to take a snapshot of your board when you add it, but that's not what it does.

Think of it like this: You have a board, and it's located at position X. You're sitting in front of your board, and you make a mark on it to indicate a possible play position. Then you hand the ArrayList a slip of paper that says "the board at position X". Then you erase the mark and make another one. Then you hand the ArrayList another slip of paper that says "the board at position X". Repeat several more times.

By the end you have an ArrayList filled with 9 slips of paper that all say "the board at position X", which is the same board you've been marking and erasing on repeatedly all this time. When you output the list, it will faithfully output that single board 9 times, and since you erased all the marks on it each printout will be empty.

To make it work, you have to make a whole new board and give a reference to *that* board to the list each time.